# Unity Android crash after loading splash image

Tags: android, crash, splash-screen

Model : JP5 MINI
CPU : 2x ARM Cortex-A9 912Mhz
GPU : Mali-400 MP2*
Screen : 480x272
RAM : 1024MB
OS: Android 4.2
Ratio : 16:9
PPI : 128.3PPI
DISPLAY SIZE : 3.74" x 2.12" = 7.93in² ( 9.5cm x 5.38cm = 51.17cm² ) at 128.3 PPI,
0.198mm dot pitch, 16462 PPI²

```
02-18 07:29:18.940: D/AudioHardware(92): AudioHardware pcm playback is exiting standby.
02-18 07:29:18.940: D/AudioHardware(92): openPcmOut_l() mPcmOpenCnt: 0
02-18 07:29:18.940: D/alsa_pcm(92): pcm_open(0x0003f000)
02-18 07:29:18.940: D/alsa_pcm(92): pcm_open() period sz multiplier 16
02-18 07:29:18.940: D/alsa_pcm(92): pcm_open() period cnt 6
02-18 07:29:18.940: D/alsa_pcm(92): pcm_open() period_cnt 6 period_sz 1024 channels 2
02-18 07:29:18.940: I/alsa_mix(92): -->Playback Path access 3
02-18 07:29:18.950: I/ActivityManager(343): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=        [android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000     cmp=com.WhyCreative.ITENO/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} from pid 541
02-18 07:29:19.000: I/ActivityManager(343): Start proc com.WhyCreative.ITENO for activity     com.WhyCreative.ITENO/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity: pid=4837 uid=10074 gids={50074, 1015,     1028, 3003}
02-18 07:29:19.040: I/InputReader(343): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
02-18 07:29:19.040: I/InputReader(343): Device reconfigured: id=2, name='gslX680', size 480x272,     orientation 3, mode 1, display id 0
02-18 07:29:19.040: I/ActivityManager(343): Config changes=1480 {1.0 ?mcc?mnc en_US ldltr sw600dp     w544dp h912dp 80dpi lrg long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.16}
02-18 07:29:19.110: D/PhoneApp(530): updateProximitySensorMode: state = IDLE
02-18 07:29:19.120: D/PhoneApp(530): updateProximitySensorMode: lock already released.
02-18 07:29:19.160: I/qtaguid(343): Failed write_ctrl(s 1 10074) res=-1 errno=1
02-18 07:29:19.160: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(343): setKernelCountSet(10074, 1) failed with     errno -1
02-18 07:29:19.230: D/dalvikvm(4837): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.WhyCreative.ITENO-    2/lib/libmain.so 0x41e10600
02-18 07:29:19.230: D/dalvikvm(4837): Added shared lib /mnt/asec/com.WhyCreative.ITENO-    2/lib/libmain.so 0x41e10600
02-18 07:29:19.240: D/WallpaperManager(417): LOAD DEFAULT WALLPAPER  ......false
02-18 07:29:19.280: D/dalvikvm(417): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1328K, 57% free 4099K/9348K, paused 30ms,     total 35ms
02-18 07:29:19.290: I/dalvikvm-heap(417): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.073MB for 4096016-byte     allocation
02-18 07:29:19.330: D/dalvikvm(417): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 206K, 41% free 7892K/13352K, paused 44ms,     total 44ms
02-18 07:29:19.420: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(541): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
02-18 07:29:19.420: I/ActivityManager(343): Displayed     com.WhyCreative.ITENO/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity: +439ms
02-18 07:29:19.450: D/dalvikvm(417): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 41% free 7890K/13352K, paused 6ms+25ms,     total 113ms
02-18 07:29:19.450: E/dalvikvm(4837): Could not find class 'java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup',     referenced from method bitter.jnibridge.JNIBridge$a.<init>
02-18 07:29:19.450: W/dalvikvm(4837): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 269     (Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;) in Lbitter/jnibridge/JNIBridge$a;
02-18 07:29:19.450: D/dalvikvm(4837): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x000b
02-18 07:29:19.450: E/dalvikvm(4837): Could not find class 'java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup',     referenced from method bitter.jnibridge.JNIBridge$a.a
02-18 07:29:19.450: W/dalvikvm(4837): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 269     (Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;) in Lbitter/jnibridge/JNIBridge$a;
02-18 07:29:19.450: D/dalvikvm(4837): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x001b
02-18 07:29:19.500: I/Unity(4837): SystemInfo CPU = ARMv7 VFPv3 NEON, Cores = 2, Memory = 1024mb
02-18 07:29:19.500: I/Unity(4837): SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 2 big (mask: 0x3), 0     little (mask: 0x0)
02-18 07:29:19.500: I/Unity(4837): ApplicationInfo com.WhyCreative.ITENO version 1.0 build 360b0e55-    e22b-42f3-ae7a-8314418d164f
02-18 07:29:19.500: I/Unity(4837): Built from '2019.1/release' branch, Version '2019.1.2f1     (3e18427e571f)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'mono', CPU 'armeabi-v7a', Stripping 'Disabled'
02-18 07:29:20.100: D/libEGL(4837): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
02-18 07:29:20.100: D/libEGL(4837): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
02-18 07:29:20.100: D/libEGL(4837): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
02-18 07:29:20.130: D/Unity(4837):  GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_texture_npot     GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_depth24     GL_ARM_rgba8 GL_ARM_mali_shader_binary GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil     GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_EGL_sync     GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_ARM_mali_program_binary GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod GL_EXT_robustness
02-18 07:29:21.690: D/dalvikvm(343): GC_EXPLICIT freed 239K, 40% free 7247K/11996K, paused 4ms+7ms,     total 80ms
02-18 07:29:22.740: V/xzj(343): Predicted: tiltAngle=-40, orientationAngle=86, predictedRotation=1, predictedRotationAgeMS=0.0
02-18 07:29:50.350: W/ThrottleService(343): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
02-18 07:32:25.590: I/EventLogService(636): Aggregate from 1298016145449 (log), 1298016145449 (data)
02-18 07:32:25.630: W/DropBoxManagerService(343): Dropping: event_data (39 > 0 bytes)
02-18 07:39:30.280: D/dalvikvm(530): GC_CONCURRENT freed 380K, 15% free 3296K/3856K, paused 2ms+9ms,     total 83ms
02-18 07:39:50.350: W/ThrottleService(343): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
```

Comment: [This lengthy thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/google-play-api-warnings-started-today.676654/) suggests you should upgrade to `2017.4.33 LTS`.

Comment: @KenY-N what do you meant by upgrading to 2017.4.33 LTS? Currently I'm using Unity 2019.1.2f1.

Comment: Ah, I see... Maybe they mean downgrade?

Comment: How does downgrading solve the issue?